# The grammar behind 爪食い込む前足そっくりの生き物 (in the いよわ song 地球の裏)

Tags: grammar, adjectives, parsing, song-lyrics

I think the definition for そっくり that would make remote sense here would be そのまま as any other definition makes less sense, not to mention the fact that the 似ている meanings are for when it's used as a 形容動詞.

Comment: The song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruBxsq03FZo

Comment: Do you mean そのまま and 似ている are distinct by 'not to mention the fact that the 似ている meanings are for when it's used as a 形容動詞.'?

Comment: そっくりな and そっくりの are both possible.

Comment: I think that if I included the のこと in 爪食い込む前足そっくりの生き物(のこと図鑑で読んだわ), it would make more sense, perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そっくり is used both as a na-adjective and a no-adjective in the same sense. 前足そっくり**な**生き物 and 前足そっくり**の**生き物 mean exactly the same thing, 前足にとても似ている生き物.

So grammatically speaking, the line just means:

> 爪(が)食い込む前足(に)**そっくりの**生き物
> a creature that **looks exactly like** a paw with claws digging in

I can't tell what metaphor this is without interpreting the entire lyrics, but as a grammatical explanation, there's nothing more complicated than this.

そっくり means そのまま or 全部 when it's used as an adverb, such as in そっくりお返しされた and そっくり受け入れる. However, when そっくり is used with の or な, it only means "looks alike".

Comment: Well, when the song is about a kasha (don't forget cats are used to test sexual sin in meido) carrying someone married to hell, the line makes absolutely less sense if そっくり can only mean 似ている with nothing omitted and not  completely or そのまま

Comment: The grammar here is definitely (前足が)爪食い込む前足そっくり, then. I really hate those type of phrases... Like 毎日飲んでるサプリメントや (What's up Pop) (and there are other weird examples but I do not remember and I do not know what this grammar pattern is called)

Comment: Oh, there's another in this song; そういう選択だ

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct (in the sense that [そっくり](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8A) here means  the same thing as [そのまま](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E3%81%BE%E3%81%BE)#2 - both 'just like').

Xにそっくり can often be shortened to Xそっくり. E.g., タマにそっくりな猫 (a cat very similar to Tama<sup>1</sup>) can be タマそっくりな猫.

The whole phrase does not make a clear sense, but 爪食い込む前足 should be 爪**が**食い込む前足.

爪が食い込む is ambiguous. It is either the nail curls into<sup>2</sup> the forefoot or the forefoot grips on something in the way the nails deeply sink into the flexible surface<sup>3</sup>. I guess the former is meant and basically it is saying the creature is grotesque.

---

<sup>1</sup> タマ is a typical cat name.

<sup>2</sup> you can search 巻き爪 to see what kind of deformation it is.

<sup>3</sup> I cannot come up with a good English description for 食い込む...

Comment: 質問者は「このそっくりは "似ている" はなく "そのまま" の意味ですよね」と聞いていますので、"Your understanding is correct" ではないのでは。多分ですけど「その言葉をそっくりお返しするよ」「そっくり信じ込んでしまった」の「そっくり」の方ですよね、と聞かれているように思います。

Comment: What answer should I approve? I mean, naruto's one was first but I didn't expect to get two elaborate answers!? I think naruto's is more accurate, but I need more elaboration... Like, how could そっくり(completely/resembling)の make any sense! I definitely spaced the sentence wrong, or it was, and tumekuikomumaeasi is inverted

Comment: Oops, Sundowner's answer came first, the page glitched. The entire sentence was translated I've read all about those creatures that seem to dig their claws in their forefeet in a encyclopedia!/I read a picture book about all the creatures that knead with their paws